# MySQL Syntax Error 1064 On Set

Tags: mysql

Let's see if I can edit this and put the whole procedure in.

I am trying to convert an Oracle database to MySQL. I have all the tables, keys, indexes, and views converted. I now need to convert a stored procedure to MySQL.

I have most of it done, and there is only one hang up on my code:

```
set dns1_tmp = X.X.X.X;
SET dns2_tmp = X.X.X.X;
```

This gives me an error of 1064 Syntax Error: Missing semicolon

I have tested the rest of my procedure, and it works fine. It creates it, runs it, and retrieves data from it, but only if I remove those two lines.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Whole stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //

USE `TEST`//

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `proc_IN`//
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `proc_IN`
(IN DNIS VARCHAR(20),
IN MSISDN VARCHAR(20),
IN AVPAIR1 VARCHAR(20),
IN AVPAIR2 VARCHAR(20),
IN GROUPID VARCHAR(20),
OUT DNS1 VARCHAR(15),
OUT DNS2 VARCHAR(15),
OUT AUTHSTAT VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
declare dns1_tmp varchar(15);
declare dns2_tmp varchar(15);
set dns1_tmp = X.X.X.X;
SET dns2_tmp = X.X.X.X;
DECLARE avpair1_tmp varchar(15);
DECLARE avpair2_tmp varchar(15);
DECLARE grpid_tmp varchar(15);

DECLARE C_USER CURSOR FOR SELECT AVPAIR1, AVPAIR2, DNS1, DNS2, GROUPID FROM GRP, ALLMEMBER WHERE ALLMEMBER.GROUPID=GRP.GROUPID
    UNION
    SELECT AVPAIR1, AVPAIR2, DNS1, DNS2, GROUPID FROM GRP; 
OPEN C_USER;
FETCH C_USER INTO AVPAIR1, AVPAIR2, DNS1, DNS2, GROUPID;
LOOP
    FETCH C_USER INTO avpair1_tmp, avpair2_tmp, dns1_tmp, dns2_tmp, grpid_tmp;
    INSERT INTO duplog VALUES(DNIS, MSISDN, avpair1_tmp, avpair2_tmp, dns1_tmp,dns2_tmp, grpid_tmp, SYSDATE);
END LOOP;
IF C_USER%ROWCOUNT > 1 THEN
        INSERT INTO duplog VALUES(DNIS, MSISDN, AVPAIR1, AVPAIR2, DNS1,DNS2, GROUPID, SYSDATE);
            SET AUTHSTAT := 'ok';
        elseif C_USER%ROWCOUNT = 1 THEN
            SET AUTHSTAT := 'ok';
ELSE
            SET AUTHSTAT := NULL;
END IF;

CLOSE C_USER;
COMMIT;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

UPDATE:

I have tried single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks. When I do the code in this fashion

```
set dns1_tmp = 'X.X.X.X';
SET dns2_tmp = 'X.X.X.X';
```

I get a different error of Syntax Error: Missing end

Comment: have you tried `set dns1_tmp = 'X.X.X.X';` ?

Comment: Yes I've tried single quotes, doubles quotes, and back ticks

Comment: On my machine I found two errors (may be different for you). I moved the `SET dns1_tmp = '1.2.3.4';` and `tmp2` below all the `DECLARE` statements, and put a `BEGIN` above `DECLARE C_USER` and an `END;` before `END//`. It then created without error. I don't know if that helps?

Comment: Should put that as the answer if possible

Comment: Often, it is practical to use @variables in Stored Routines.  CURSORs are inefficient; it looks like that could be turned into two (because of UNION) `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statements.  I doubt if `C_USER%ROWCOUNT` will do what you expect.

Comment: glad to help, will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The IP Addresses in your `DNSx_tmp` variables need to be enclosed in single quotes in order to make them character strings (as they have been Declared).

The `SET DNSx_tmp;` variables need to be moved below all the `DECLARE` statements.

You also need to add a `BEGIN` clause above `DECLARE c_user` and the matching `END` clause before your final `END`clause.